# Iterating Through Pandas Dataframe Checking For Logical Conditions At Different Indexes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am trying to iterate through a pandas dataframe and simply check for duplicates. If a duplicate 'ID' field exists then compare the 'BeginTime' field of the duplicates and assign a new time based on the results of several if/elif/else comparisons. The trouble I am running into is that I don't know how to compare logical conditions of 'ID' at different indexes of the dataframe. When I run the code the output for checking for duplicates is correct but I am not getting any new times assigned. This is what I have so far...

Desired Output for the duplicates is as follows:
9999,
1250,
1130,
either 1130 or 1250,
1250,
9999

```
import pandas as import pd 

# dataframe initialized
dfmwf = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [97330, 97330, 95232, 95232, 91293, 91293, 92471, 92471, 92471, 91616, 
                          97297, 97297, 94305, 94305, 94305], 
                   'BeginTime': [1135, 1255, 1135, 1415, 1255, 1415, 1415, 1415, 1415, 1255, 1135, 
                                 1135, 1135,1255, 1415]})
# set counter for testing purposes
count = 0

# iterate through the dataframe rows
for index, row in dfmwf.iterrows():

# check if a duplicate, this seems to be working fine   
  if dfmwf.loc[index, 'ID'] == dfmwf.shift(+1).loc[index, 'ID']:
       print(count, 'yes')
       count += 1

# check multiple conditions of duplicates, this block of code is not working at all           
       if dfmwf.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1255 and dfmwf.shift(-1).loc[index, 'ID'] == 1135:
               print('New time = 1250')
       elif dfmwf.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1415 and dfmwf.shift(-1).loc[index, 'ID'] == 1135:
               print('New time = 1130')
       elif dfmwf.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1415 and dfmwf.shift(-1).loc[index, 'ID'] == 1255:
               print('New time = either
       elif dfmwf.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1135 and dfmwf.shift(-1).loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1255 and dfmwf.shift(-2).loc[index, 'ID'] == 1415:   
               print('New time = 9999')  
  else:
      print(count, 'no, New time = 9999') 
      count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you use shift(+1) when checking for duplicates, but shift(-1) and shift(-2) for your conditions on the duplicates. This would mean you are looking at the second and third duplicate IDs but then looking at the following cases which aren't necessarily the same ID.

I think the function you are really after is `iloc`, which can be used as `.iloc[index-1]` Modifying your code using iloc, and fixing some typos looks as below.

```
# check if a duplicate, this seems to be working fine
  if dfmwf.loc[index, 'ID'] == dfmwf.iloc[index-1]['ID']:
       # print(count, 'yes')
       count += 1

# check multiple conditions of duplicates, this block of code is not working at all
       if dfmwf.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1255 and dfmwf.iloc[index-1]['BeginTime'] == 1135:
               print('New time = 1250')
       elif dfmwf.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1415 and dfmwf.iloc[index-1]['BeginTime'] == 1135:
               print('New time = 1130')
       elif dfmwf.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1415 and dfmwf.iloc[index-1]['BeginTime'] == 1255:
               print('New time = either')
       elif dfmwf.loc[index, 'BeginTime'] == 1135 and dfmwf.iloc[index-1]['BeginTime'] == 1255 and dfmwf.iloc[index-2]['BeginTime'] == 1415:
               print('New time = 9999')
```

This gives the following output:

```
0 no, New time = 9999
1 yes
New time = 1250
2 no, New time = 9999
3 yes
New time = 1130
4 no, New time = 9999
5 yes
New time = either
6 no, New time = 9999
7 yes
8 yes
9 no, New time = 9999
10 no, New time = 9999
11 yes
12 no, New time = 9999
13 yes
New time = 1250
14 yes
New time = either
```

Additionally, I would avoid iterating through the entire dataframe.

```
for id in df.ID.unique(): # iterate through all unique id's
   this_id = df.loc[df.ID == id]
   if len(t.index)<=1: #if there is only one entry of this ID
         print(count, 'no, New time = 9999')    
         continue
   # check the conditions on the subset 'this_id'
```

Comment: I tried to use the code you suggested but ended up with a KeyError: 94305 for the line of code:                if dfmwf.loc[index, 'ID'] == dfmwf.iloc[index-1]['ID']:    Not sure what happened. Where are you placing the iteration for only uniique() id's?